# Do I need Playstation Plus to play Star Trek Online on PS4?

Tags: playstation-plus, star-trek-online

I can´t find conclusive information about this. Since some games require PlayStation Plus subscription (Like Planetside 2) does this game require PS+?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, any online PS4 game requires Playstation Plus.

Comment: Not quite. I know for sure some games does not require PS+ to play (Free to play) but some of the Free to play list does need a subscription.

Comment: @Zarathustrax Well, if Star Trek Online isn't a free-to-play game, chances are it requires PS+.

Answer (score -1):

Star Trek Online on PS4 is a free to play game so it doesn't require a PS+ subscription. I can back this up because i play it on PS4 without PS+ ;D. Same for Neverwinter.

Answer (score -3):

Star Trek Online on PS4 is a free to play game so it doesn't require a PS+ subscription.

Comment: We have a different answer, over a year old, that contradicts this.  Do you have anything to back up this statement?